# Travis-CI & Symfony 3.2 "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" error

Tags: php, symfony, travis-ci

I'm facing some problem while building on travis my `Symfony 3.2` project.
After downloading all dependencies it gives me the following error message:

> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   Could not open input file: app/console
>   Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception

And I get a RuntimeException:

> [RuntimeException]
>   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
>   Could not open input file: app/console

[Here is the full Job Log.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/190476436/log.txt)

and the configuration:

```
 {
  "language": "php",
  "php": "7.0",
  "before_script": [
    "composer install"
  ],
  "global_env": "SOURCE_DIR=src VHOST_FILE=.travis.vhost",
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "precise",
  "os": "linux"
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `bin/console` instead of `app/console` since Symfony 3.x?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason travis keeps looking under app directory. The current fix I'm using is to copy the console into the app directory.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you deleted your `var` directory or you don't have `.gitkeep` files in it.
It is a known issue :

https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/issues/301

Try to create `.gitkeep`files for in your `var/cache`, `var/logs` and `var/sessions` directories.

This could resolve the problem